# 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout' in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Could you please help me with identifying the error

```
'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'
```

which I am getting while running an Ansible playbook. Please see the error below:

```json
{"msg": "The conditional check '(result.stdout == 1) and (ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'RedHat')' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ((result.stdout == 1) and (ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'RedHat')): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbooks/dev_patching_security_upgrade_version2.yml': line 47, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Reboot CentOS Server if Necessary\n      ^ here\n"}
```

I am pasting the relevant part of the code below:

```yaml
- name: check to see if we need a reboot in Centos
  shell:
     "needs-restarting; echo $?"
  register: result
  ignore_errors: yes
  when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'RedHat'

- name: display result
  debug:
    var: result.stdout
  when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'RedHat'

- name: Reboot CentOS Server if Necessary
  command: shutdown -r now "Ansible Updates Triggered reboot"
  become: true
  async: 30
  poll: 0
  when: (result.stdout == 1) and (ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'RedHat')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put the checks for the value of `ansible_distribution` before the check for `result.stdout==1` in the last `when` clause. What's happening, I think, is that when you're not on CentOS or Redhat, `result` is not set at all (or it still has a value from a previous thing - I would suggest using more meaningful variable names for that reason)

Comment: @Jelaby , Yes changing the position worked.  Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is because the result set might not have a dictionary key `stdout`. To [debug a result set](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html#examples) you may use

```yaml
- name: Show result
  debug:
    var: result
```

Since the shell module already provides the return code within the [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#return-values), reboot checks are simple as

```yaml
- name: Check if reboot_required
  shell:
    cmd: "needs-restarting -r"
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: reboot_required.rc != 0 and reboot_required.rc != 1
  check_mode: false
  register: reboot_required

- name: Report reboot_required
  debug:
    msg: "{{  reboot_required.rc | bool }} "
  changed_when: reboot_required.rc == 1
  check_mode: false
```

and resulting into an output of in example

```
TASK [Report reboot_required] **************************************************
ok: [test1.example.com] => {
    "msg": "True "
}
ok: [test2.example.com] => {
    "msg": "False "
}
```

You could dense down the tasks to one by using one

```bash
needs-restarting -r || /usr/sbin/shutdown -r now "Ansible Updates Triggered reboot"
```

**Further Q&A**

- [How to determine if system needs a reboot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690333/266568)
- [Ansible - How to reboot the server based on condition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707238/266568)